# How to customize face when use 'org-edit-latex-environment?

Tags: org-mode, latex, faces, customization

When use `org-edit-latex-environment`(which opens another buffer so `latex` source code can be edited in more sophiscated environment, e.g. `LaTeX`) in `org-mode`, the source block will be highlight as yellow (just as figure below), which is kind of distracting. So, how can I customize this, for  example, how to change the color?
[image]

Comment: OK. I 've put that as an answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put your cursor on the yellow text and use `C-u C-x =`.
2. Look near the bottom of the resulting `*Help*` buffer for mention of what the face is that is used.
3. Then use `M-x customize-face` to customize that face.